# Using Leibnitz Integral rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show this using Leibnitz rule:

$$D_2f(x,y) = \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}} \left ( \int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds \right)$$
$$= \int_0^x \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}} g_1(t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}} g_2(x,s) \ ds$$
$$ = \int_0^x \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}} g_1(t,0) \ dt + g_2(x,y) - g(x,0)$$

How do I calculate the first integral?

Comment: Why not just use the FTC?

Comment: @zhw. I am not sure how. I used it for the second integral.

Comment: When $x$ is fixed, you have something of the form $a(y) = C +\int_0^y b(s)\,ds.$

Comment: @zhw. I really don't follow what you're referencing too - which integral do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$ \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}} \left ( \int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds \right)=0+g_2(x,y)=g_2(x,y)$$
because $\int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt$ doesn't have any $y$, i.e. constant with respect to $y$.

also note that 
$$ \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}}\int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds\ne \int_0^y  \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}}g_2(x,s) $$
but
$$ \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}}\int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds = 
\frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}}\left(G_2(x,y)-G_2(x,0)\right)=g_2(x,y)
$$
where $G_2$ is antiderivative of $g_2$ with respect to $y$, i.e.
$\frac{d}{dy}G_2(x,y)=g_2(x,y)$

Comment: That's originally what I had also - but that implies $D_2f(x,y) = g_2(x,y) - g_2(x,0)$ which is incorrect unless $g_2(x,0) = 0$

Comment: sorry,   fixed it

Comment: could you explain the second part? why $d/dy G_2(x,0) = 0$?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky thanks I got it now - if you have time could you take a look at my second question I posted a while back?